# Trace: TypeError: f.getRuleSeverity is not a function

Tags: grafana, lint

I am working on a Grafana plugin development on linux (ubuntu) machine. Versions which i am using are

Grafana : 6.3.5

Grafana toolkit : 6.4.4

Grafana UI : 6.3.2

I am using React for plugin development. I cloned the code from [React Panel Plugin](https://github.com/grafana/simple-react-panel) in the plugins directory of grafana. I installed the required dependencies and packages. After that i build the plugin using `yarn build`. Plugin works fine and is displayed on the grafana.

Now, i have to use syncFusion library in my plugin because i am developing a plugin which will display SmithChart. I added the syncFusion package through `npm install @syncfusion/ej2-react-charts --save`. I got that from [SyncFusion](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/smithchart/getting-started/). Now when i build my plugin using `yarn build`, i get the error `Trace: TypeError: f.getRuleSeverity is not a function`. Complete result of `yarn build` is:

```
yarn run v1.21.1
$ grafana-toolkit plugin:build
✔ Cleaning
✔ Preparing
✔ Prettier check
⠋ Linting

Trace: TypeError: f.getRuleSeverity is not a function
  at /aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/src/cli/tasks/plugin.build.js:179:44
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at /aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/src/cli/tasks/plugin.build.js:177:34
  at step (/aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
  at Object.next (/aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:57)
  at fulfilled (/aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:62)
  at /aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/src/cli/utils/useSpinner.js:24:29
  at step (/aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
  at Object.throw (/aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:57)
  at rejected (/aedata/ae/grafana/plugins/simple-react-panel/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:108:69)
✖ f.getRuleSeverity is not a function
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I googled it but could not find any help. I also tried `npm i lint` but to no success. What can be the possible issue. Is there a problem with syncFusion package because before syncFusion the plugin builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on grafana github and came to know that this was an issue with grafana which they have resolved now. [This](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/21846) is the link of the issue.